# Not getting PostgreSQL function result back in Java ResultSet

Tags: java, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL function that returns a record from database that I would like to call from my Java code, but when I call that function I get a exception saying "The column name app_uri was not found in this ResultSet.". I get this error when it tries to get "rs.getString("api_url")". So, to debug the issue I used resultset getMetaData() to make sure the columns that I am expecting is there. However, it seems those columns(app_uri, endpoint_name, endpoint_uri) are not there and instead it returns the name of the function(create).

When I run a query in PGAdmin that calls the PostgreSQL create function, it returns the record columns(app_uri, endpoint_name, endpoint_uri) as expected. So, I am not sure if I am not getting the record columns values in my Java code, because of some error in the PostgreSQL function or in my Java code. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is a sample of my PostgreSQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create ( 
    service_instance_id text, 
    )
RETURNS service_info_for_create AS $$
DECLARE
    r service_info_for_create%rowtype;
BEGIN   
    -- Return service info
    select app_uri, endpoint_name, endpoint_uri from    get_service(service_instance_id) into r;
    RETURN r;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Here is a sample of my Java code:

```
CallableStatement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

stmt = connListen.prepareCall("select * from       create('sysname1003_servicenameSteven13')");
rs = stmt.executeQuery();

if (!rs.next()) {
    provLogger.info("No service_info_for_create results.");
} else {
    ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
    int count = metaData.getColumnCount(); //number of column
    provLogger.info("number of columns: '" + count + "'");

    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
    {
        provLogger.info(i + " column name: '" + metaData.getColumnName(i) + "'");
        provLogger.info(i + " column label: '" + metaData.getColumnLabel(i) + "'");
    }

    provLogger.info("api_url: " + rs.getString("api_uri"));
    provLogger.info("endpoint_name: " + rs.getString("endpoint_name"));
    provLogger.info("endpoint_uri: " + rs.getString("endpoint_uri"));
}
```

Here is part of the log:

`[2015-12-16T02:36:24.104-05:00] [managed01] [NOTIFICATION] [] [logging] [tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [userId: <anonymous>] [ecid: 71f08ae4e54ff54e:6ed4bd6e:15188eb8b84:-8000-0000000000003682,0] [APP: socpro] number of columns: '1'
[2015-12-16T02:36:24.104-05:00] [managed01] [NOTIFICATION] [] [logging] [tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [userId: <anonymous>] [ecid: 71f08ae4e54ff54e:6ed4bd6e:15188eb8b84:-8000-0000000000003682,0] [APP: socpro] 1 column name: 'create'
[2015-12-16T02:36:24.104-05:00] [managed01] [NOTIFICATION] [] [logging] [tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [userId: <anonymous>] [ecid: 71f08ae4e54ff54e:6ed4bd6e:15188eb8b84:-8000-0000000000003682,0] [APP: socpro] 1 column label: 'create'
[2015-12-16T02:36:24.109-05:00] [managed01] [ERROR] [ERROR-1200: Abort transaction.A Listen service error has occurred. Error message = The column name app_uri was not found in this ResultSet.] [logging] [tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [userId: <anonymous>] [ecid: 71f08ae4e54ff54e:6ed4bd6e:15188eb8b84:-8000-0000000000003682,0] [APP: socpro] [requestID: requestID] [dataDomain: dataDomain] ERROR-1200: Abort transaction.A Listen service error has occurred. Error message = The column name app_uri was not found in this ResultSet.
[2015-12-16T02:36:24.111-05:00] [managed01] [NOTIFICATION] [] [logging] [tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [userId: <anonymous>] [ecid: 71f08ae4e54ff54e:6ed4bd6e:15188eb8b84:-8000-0000000000003682,0] [APP: socpro] Inside releaseConnection
[2015-12-16T02:36:24.111-05:00] [managed01] [ERROR] [InvalidSubscriptionException Exeption. Create failed. Rolling back changes: {0}] [logging] [tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [userId: <anonymous>] [ecid: 71f08ae4e54ff54e:6ed4bd6e:15188eb8b84:-8000-0000000000003682,0] [APP: socpro] [requestID: requestID] [dataDomain: dataDomain] [[
socpro.InvalidSubscriptionException: ERROR-1200: Abort transaction.A Listen service error has occurred. Error message = The column name app_uri was not found in this ResultSet.
    at socpro.SocialSubscriptionOperations.createListenServiceAndSubscriptions(SocialSubscriptionOperations.java:464)
    at socpro.SocialSubscriptionOperations.createListenSubscription(SocialSubscriptionOperations.java:203)
    at socpro.SDaaSProvisioningResourceImpl.createService(SDaaSProvisioningResourceImpl.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)`

Comment: Why does your sample java code display only the metadata? You're not even looking at the results.

Comment: Your Java code only retrieves the ***names of the columns*** in the resultset, not any of the data.

Comment: It may not solve the problem, but you need to call `next()` before calling `getString`

Comment: Sorry. The metadata was for debugging purposes. I've added some code showing the resultset usage, plus I've updated the description with more details about the issue I am having.

Comment: Mark, I called `next()` before calling `getString`, but I still get the error.

Comment: Your Java is referencing a column named `api_url` but your stored procedure is referencing `app_uri`.

Comment: Can you show us what's in the log file?

Comment: Sorry, for the typo in the sample code. It is correct in my actual code, so that is not the cause of it. I've add a part of the log file above.

Comment: I found the cause of the error. The query was not correct and therefore there was no results in the resultset.